# Does scavenging affect Division Tech boxes?

Tags: the-division

The information on the *scavenging* stat is very vague at the moment.

Does anyone have the definitive answers to the following questions:

1. Does it affect the type of Division Tech from boxes in the Dark Zone?
2. Does it affect the RNG rolls on items found? Or just the overall item levels of items found (so finding a gold instead of a purple etc)?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6m9yY7LihM

Comment: I can't answer that, but some experienced players says the scavenging stat doesn't change anything at all. I have used 88% and 133% scavenging bonus and didn't noticed any better drops compared to other players in my group.

Comment: I recently acquired 2 pieces of the nomad set, which provided me with a bonus 100% scavenging, and I have been unable to notice the difference.

Comment: I can confirm that I see no difference between what I get from boxes with or without Nomad pieces. It only seems to affect drops from killed enemies.

Answer (score 3):

As of the 1.4 patch to The Division, Scavenging has been removed from all pieces of gear. It no longer has any affect in the game.

Answer (score 0):

It only affects the quality (green/blue/yellow) and not the quantity of drops.

You can read more [here](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1423326-NEWS-Mar-29-2016-Division-State-of-Game-Cliff-Notes)